# HP:the arguments in killall beyond `man killall`

Tags: kill, arguments, syntax

In the tutorial here :
[/usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd](http://xmodulo.com/logrotate-manage-log-files-linux.html)

For the command :

```
/usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd
```

In my os,the synopsis info in `man killall`

```
SYNOPSIS
       killall [-Z, --context pattern] [-e, --exact] [-g, --process-group]
       [-i, --interactive] [-o, --older-than TIME] [-q, --quiet] [-r, --reg‐
       exp] [-s, --signal SIGNAL, -SIGNAL] [-u, --user user] [-v, --verbose]
       [-w, --wait] [-y, --younger-than TIME] [-I, --ignore-case] [-V, --ver‐
       sion] [--] name ...
       killall -l
       killall -V, --version
```

U means user here.
No argument `H` or `P`,what does  `HP`  in `/usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd` mean ?
How to get the definitions of `HP` ?

Comment: Have a look at [man killall](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) and you'll see that `HUP` (or [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP)) refers to the name of a signal.

Comment: The manual page synopsis says that one way to use `killall` is `killall -SIGNAL name...`. In the example in the question, `SIGNAL` is `HUP`; so the example in the question sends SIGHUP to all processes running `rsyslogd`.

Comment: Looks like an answer, @John1024 or @AlexP!

Answer (score 1):

The `-HUP` that you read as three options, `-H`, `-U` and `-P` is an instance of what the synopsis lists as `-SIGNAL`, i.e. a signal name prefixed by a dash.

The `HUP` signal is the "hang-up" signal, usually sent to a shell to terminate it.  The signal is also commonly used to let daemon processes (like `rsyslogd`) know that they should re-read their configuration files or restart etc.

The command `killall -HUP rsyslogd` sends the `HUP` signal to all processes whose name is `rsyslogd`.

You could also use `pkill`:

```
pkill -HUP rsyslogd
```

or, to use the signal *number* instead of the signal name (check the numbers with `kill -l`, but there's almost never a reason to use the numbers),

```
pkill -1 rsyslogd
```